# How can I get the device string of a physics phone?

Tags: android, android-studio

In order not to violate policy of Google AdMob AD, I add my physics phone to test device using Code A.

I get the device string "Samsung SM-J5008" of the physics phone using the following UI when I select a device to run the App.

I don't know whether the string "Samsung SM-J5008" is correct, and more the Google AD is still displayed even if I have added the code `.addTestDevice("Samsung SM-J5008")`

**And More**

I don't need to remove addTestDevice() when I publish my app, all physical phones will display AD except these physical phones who's name string listed in addTestDevice(), is it right?

[image]

**Code A**

```
 val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("Samsung GT-I9268")
                .addTestDevice("Samsung SM-J5008")
                .build()
  adView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Comment: What is a physics phone ?

Comment: Samsung SM-J5008

Comment: @nimi0112 i think he mean physical phone not emulator.

Comment: Yes, I test my app both physical phone and emulator, so I need add test device both physical phone and emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the project, if you monitor the LogCat, you can find a similar line **Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice(“C04B1BFFB0774708339BC273F8A43708”) to get test ads on this device**. Copy the device id and add it to AdRequest.

**Note** that this ID varies from device to device, By doing this, the test ads will be loaded instead of live ads.

In **production** you need to make sure that you removed `addTestDevice()` methods in order to render the live ads and start monetization.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need to remove addTestDevice() when I publish my app, all physical phones will display AD except these physical phones who's name string listed in addTestDevice(), right?

Comment: yes if you didn't remove other devices will show except those.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are running admob ads on an emulator then there is no ID. just use the AdManager method and set it to TEST_EMULATOR like the logcat says. If you run on an actual device with usb debugging and watch the logcat, the ID will appear in there.You need to add device ID As :**

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String deviceId = md5(android_id).toUpperCase();
Log.i("device id=",deviceId);
```